# Unable to see Procedures item in a schema in Microsoft Azure PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I developed a stored procedure in PostgreSQL in my local machine. And going to deploy it to PostgreSQL in MS Azure. But it's so strange, I did not see "Procedure" item inside a schema.

In Azure

[image: In Azure]

In my local

[image: In my local]

I guess the user I have used in Azure does not have some permissions to view "Procedures".

If you know about this, please advise me.

Thank,

Comment: What is your Postgres version on Azure? Procedures were introduced in Postgres 11 (the most recent version). Probably the Postgres version on Azure is earlier than that. Run `select version();` to check

Comment: The version is "PostgreSQL 10.5, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit". So with this version, I have to convert from Store Procedure to Function?

Comment: Yes, Postgres 10 only allows functions.